# Check if List<String> startsWith another String using Stream.of

Tags: java, android, java-8, stream, android-databinding

I have List witch contain two different url

my urls :

```
https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music111/v4/31/5b/62/315b62fb-3b46-d2ee-5833-be210d3287f7/source/100x100bb.jpg
```

and

```
https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/5ed371a8b6d03258d597eb661805baee.png
```

I would like to switch icon image in my AdaperRecyclerView (comparing the beginning of a url) , but my loop dont work like I would like.

my code for switch image:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SongHolder holder, int possition) {

    // Source image swicher
    holder.binding.setModelItem(localArtistNameList.get(possition));
    if( Stream.of(localSourceList).anyMatch((s) -> s.startsWith("https://is"))){
        holder.binding.sourceIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_source_itune);
    }else {
        holder.binding.sourceIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_source_lastfm);
    }

    holder.binding.executePendingBindings();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return localArtistNameList.size();
}
```

my issue is that icon cannot change. I debag it and for and for simplicity  I did print screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
holder.binding.setModelItem(localArtistNameList.get(possition));
holder.binding.sourceIcon.setBackgroundResource(localArtistNameList.get(i).startWith("https://is") ? R.drawable.icon_source_itune : R.drawable.icon_source_lastfm);
holder.binding.executePendingBindings();
```

Comment: I will change my code, your code is more elegant, get(possition) fix issue.